# Custom asp.net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, membership

I am implementing a custom membership provider by inheriting from MembershipProvider. I have my own database schema that is different from the aspnet membership schema.

I do not have any use of the password field and I was wondering how can I override the builtin CreateUserWizard control?

I was unable to find any examples on how to build my own CreateUserWizrd control that is wired with my custom membership provider. The examples I found were to customize the existing CreateUserWizard by using the templates in the control.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few choices. One is as was suggested, just change the template. Another (and better, although much more work) would be to pop open the control in reflector to see how it works, then extend it and override the relevant bits to remove references to password.

The third (and what I would recommend) is to just roll your own. The `Membership`, `Roles`, and `Profile` classes are all fairly easy to work with, and the `CreateUserWizard` is fairly heavy weight. Unless it is exactly what I need, I usually throw together a user control that does it anyways, even when using the default provider.